# Setup Windows Server Local DNS on WAN

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I inherited a WAN with centrally hosted DNS,AD Servers. I have clients connecting to Application Servers hosted locally on site. Problem is when the WAN link goes down clients can't connect to Application Servers or any of the Local Servers. DHCP is hosted locally. DNS and AD are hosted at Headquarters.

Any recommendations on how I can eliminate this problem? Setting up Secondary DCs is not an option as there over 80 sites linked to the WAN.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify it and provide some more details?

Comment: Thank you joeqwerty for your response.This is the setup.Our Primary & secondary DNS and AD Servers are located offsite at Headquarters.Our offices are linked via WAN.When the WAN link goes down users can't access the local resources such local Application servers.We get the domain can not be contacted error message on logon screens.That's the problem.

Comment: OK. Understood. The users *should* be able to logon with cached credentials even when the WAN link is down but that isn't going to help with accessing the application servers. What you need is to have domain controllers in those remote offices so that clients can continue to authenticate to the domain and access the application servers when the WAN link is down.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.We have over 80 remote sites.Thanks for taking time to share your insight.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind losing dynamic DNS updates from client computers you could install Windows DNS or BIND-based secondary DNS servers in the remote sites. Unfortunately, only AD-integrated replica DNS servers (running on Domain Controller computers) will be capable of receiving dynamic updates from clients.

I suppose that, as a bit of a middle-ground solution, you could configure your remote DHCP servers to perform dynamic updates on behalf of the clients targeted at the read/write replicas of DNS at the headquarters. The client computers in each remote office could be configured to use the read-only secondaries located in their site. You'd get dynamic updates and the clients in the remote site would still have DNS availability during a WAN outage.

Comment: Thank you Evan for your response.Sounds like a workable solution but I will still have issues with users failing to authenticate when the AD is offline. It appears some profiles do not store logon credentials.